# Access Managed bean classes from a different project

Tags: maven, jsf-2

I want to access a `@ManagedBean` from *Project 2* in a different *Project 1*, but it's value is always `null`. I tried to add a `src/main/webapp/META-INF/faces-config.xml` file to *Project 2*, but it didn't help.

*Project 2* is added as a `.jar` in *Project 1*. The issue I'm facing is that the `.jar` doesn't contain the `META-INF/faces-config.xml` file.

How can I have this file correctly added to the `.jar` during my maven project build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place `faces-config.xml` in `src/main/resources/META-INF`. If you're building a `.jar`, having a `webapp` folder doesn't make any sense.

So be sure you have it in `src/main/resources/META-INF/faces-config.xml`.

Comment: Thank you. Adding it in resources folder fixed the issue.