# how to use managed Bean in another project in the same Java EE application

Tags: java, jsf-2, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6

i have a question if it´s possible to use a ManagedBean of project web X in another project web Y that both are in the same Enterprise application?

*Any help would be appreciated Thanks.*

Comment: yes, see this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551372/access-managed-bean-classes-from-a-different-project][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551372/access-managed-bean-classes-from-a-different-project

Comment: thanks @MrMins ,but i am confused. i have to create face-config in the proyect web Y and add something this:

`<managed-bean>
<managed-bean-name>mangedBean1</managed-bean-name>
   <managed-bean-class>com.package.loginweb.seguridad.myManagedBean1</managed-bean-class>
   <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
   <managed-property>
     <property-name>myVariable</property-name>
   </managed-property>
</managed-bean>`

it´s right? or need more config in this file?

Comment: in this case not found the class, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a *Jar* which goes into your final Java EE application (referenced by both of the projects if you're using Maven). Then, add the simplest faces configuration file in your *Jar*'s META-INF directory:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```

That will make JSF scan this *Jar*'s content. After that, just use **annotations** in the classes you want them to be managed beans:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SessionScopedBean{

....

}
```

That's all, for more info you can visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7663898/1199132).